# MySQL Select the field as Distinct having data type as Text with filtering

Tags: mysql, distinct

If we have a table `T1` with a field named `orders` have data type as `Text`.

> Such as the following:

```
user:1|number:2|expiry:9/2018
user:3|number:2|expiry:9/2018
user:1|number:3|expiry:1/2020
```

And i would like to `SELECT` `DISTINCT` based on `number:` and `expiry:`

So expected output gonna be:

```
user:1|number:2|expiry:9/2018
user:1|number:3|expiry:1/2020
```

How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider to restructure your data and save these details in separate columns or in another table and in different columns to avoid such structural issues.

For now with existing structure you could use aggregation to get your expected data

```
select min(orders) orders
from table1
group by substring_index(orders,'|',-2)
```

http://rextester.com/GLT33046

Comment: can you explain for me what's mean `substring_index(orders,'|',-2)`

Comment: @MichaelLucas this fucntion just breaks the text by separator like `|` and last argument from where to pick the text in your case i have specified -2 to pick the text after first pipe or pick text from second last pipe , You can run this query to get actual output for the function `select substring_index(orders,'|',-2)  from table1`